# How To select all radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript

When i click One Main Select radio button,it should select all the radio buttons in my Form.The same Way When I deselect The any one of the radio Button,it should deselect the main Radio Button(which is used to select all the radio button).

Comment: even all radio buttons `name` same? , you should read more different between radio and checkbox

Comment: no the radio buttons name are different

Comment: Hi Tushar, not a checkBox its Radio Button

Comment: The whole point of radio buttons is that only one in a group can be selected.

Comment: In my case document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution for the above issue. It looks like this:

```
function onClickHeader(ele) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (ele.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont do that. If you want to select all then better use the checkbox. Radio buttons have a different purpose.

Something like this:

```
var checked=false;
function checkedAll () {
    var aa =  document.getElementsByName("name1");
    checked = document.getElementById('name1').checked;

    for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++) 
    {
        aa[i].checked = checked;
    }
 }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TYpjQ/14/)**

Answer (score 1):

> Use checkbox but apply style like radio button.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/twL24ezb/)

Aplly this css to your checkbox

```
 input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-appearance: radio;    /* Firefox */
    -ms-appearance: radio;     /* not currently supported */
}
```

Or use input box for various function see this link http://demo.hongkiat.com/css3-checkbox-radio/